# Flutter : I need clean way to use youtube_explode_dart Package to save video

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i use this package :

> youtube_explode_dart

and i found this method to download video

```
  Future<void> downloadVideo(id) async {
    var permisson = await Permission.storage.request();
    if (permisson.isGranted) {
      //download video
      if (_urlTextFieldController.text != '') {
        setState(() => _downloading = true);

        //download video
        setState(() => progress = 0);
        var _youtubeExplode = YoutubeExplode();
        //get video metadata
        var video = await _youtubeExplode.videos.get(id);
        var manifest =
            await _youtubeExplode.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(id);
        var streams = manifest.muxed.withHighestBitrate();
        var audio = streams;
        var audioStream = _youtubeExplode.videos.streamsClient.get(audio);
        //create a directory
        Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
        var file = File('$appDocPath/${video.id}');
        //delete file if exists
        if (file.existsSync()) {
          file.deleteSync();
        }
        var output = file.openWrite(mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);
        var size = audio.size.totalBytes;
        var count = 0;

        await for (final data in audioStream) {
          // Keep track of the current downloaded data.
          count += data.length;
          // Calculate the current progress.
          double val = ((count / size));
          var msg = '${video.title} Downloaded to $appDocPath/${video.id}';
          for (val; val == 1.0; val++) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(msg)));
          }
          setState(() => progress = val);

          // Write to file.
          output.add(data);
        }
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('add youtube video url first!')));
        setState(() => _downloading = false);
      }
    } else {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
  }
```

when the method was done Scaffold Messenger send message **video wad downloaded** but i can't found the video in gallery or in local storage

i use real device Android and i was add all permission to Android manifest .

anyone can help me :(

Comment: What exactly was the scaffold message? It should have contained the path to the file.
If you can't remember, download another video and look at the given path.

Comment: @Banana the path **/data/user/0/com.ckhj.test/app_flutter/3cfdal0NGNY** and thnx for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be that you are using the path_provider function "getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()" to store the files. By replacing above Function with "getExternalStorageDirectory()" you would able to store the file in the external directory to appear in gallery. If that doesn’t work you can also use this plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

Comment: Thanks for answer.. How can I save using **gallery_saver** ? Any example :&

Comment: The repo contains an example but you pass the path to this function and it does the rest GallerySaver.saveVideo(path)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Media Scanning library, Once your file downloads, add this one line of code `MediaScanner.loadMedia(path: path);`, this will reload the media, and the downloaded content will show up in your gallery.

You have to add this Flutter media scanner package
https://pub.dev/packages/media_scanner